# Method of controlling BIND 9 from .NET app?

Tags: bind, .net, remote

We have a WCMS that allows the user to add in domains they've purchased through us to their site manager, which is supposed to instantly work. In order for this to be, we need to be able to have the WCMS make changes to the DNS (add new domains, A records, etc). The user will not be able to access the dirty details, but the app itself must be able to.

The WCMS is in .NET and runs on Windows 2003 or 2008. The DNS server is BIND9 on a separate, unixy machine. Is there an interface out there already for this, or do we need to roll our own? Note that using Microsoft DNS is not an option for this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be to use .NET or dnscmd to make the changes on a Micrsoft DNS server. The BIND server could configured as a secondary DNS. If the MS DNS server were setup to send a DNS notify, the BIND server should update itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary ways to control BIND 9, which you likely already know.  Option one is to control it via the rndc communication path; option 2 is to speak through DDNS for updates to existing zones.  Chances are you will have to use some combination of both: one to add a zone and one to update its contents.

I do know [ISC provides development services](http://www.isc.org/services/development) so perhaps dropping them a line might get you up faster?

I found very little stuff when searching for DNS and .NET other than bits here and there that speak DDNS.  It seems most people are happy using MS's DNS.  I can't imagine why...